# Why does mysqli set string to 0?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to update a table with data that has been POSTed to PHP. It takes all the values from the form and inputs them, except for emp_firstName. Emp_firstName always updates as '0' in the database, while the rest get the proper value.

emp_edit.php:

```
<?php
include '../part1/DBConnection.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if (!($result = $conn->prepare("UPDATE employees SET emp_firstName=?, emp_lastName=?, emp_middleName=?, emp_type=?, emp_initialLevel=?, emp_hireDate=?, emp_gender=?, emp_birthDate=?, emp_passwd=? WHERE emp_id=?"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $result->errno . ") " . $result->error;
  }
  if (!$result->bind_param("isssssssss", $emp_firstName, $emp_lastName, $emp_middleName, $emp_type, $emp_initialLevel, $emp_hireDate, $emp_gender, $emp_birthDate, $emp_passwd, $emp_id)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $result->errno . ") " . $result->error;
  }

  // populate param vars
  if (isset($_POST['emp_firstName'])) {
    $emp_firstName = $_POST['emp_firstName'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_lastName'])) {
    $emp_lastName = $_POST['emp_lastName'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_middleName'])) {
    $emp_middleName = $_POST['emp_middleName'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_type'])) {
    $emp_type = $_POST['emp_type'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_initialLevel'])) {
    $emp_initialLevel = $_POST['emp_initialLevel'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_hireDate'])) {
    $emp_hireDate = $_POST['emp_hireDate'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_gender'])) {
    $emp_gender = $_POST['emp_gender'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_birthDate'])) {
    $emp_birthDate = $_POST['emp_birthDate'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_passwd'])) {
    $emp_passwd = $_POST['emp_passwd'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['emp_id'])) {
    $emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
  }


  $result->execute();

  print_r($_POST);
  
  $conn->close();
}
```

and this is the result of printing the POST array (notice firstName isn't set to 0):

```
Array ( [emp_id] => 2 [emp_firstName] => John [emp_lastName] => Doe [emp_middleName] => M [emp_type] => FT [emp_initialLevel] => 1 [emp_hireDate] => 2021-03-10 [emp_gender] => M [emp_birthDate] => 1990-02-27 [emp_passwd] => 123 )
```

And the result:

```
  2 | 0             | Doe          | M              | FT       | 1                | 2021-03-10   | M          | 1990-02-27    | 123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$types` parameter specifies that the first character should be an integer:

```
isssssssss
^
|
Means integer
```

Just make it a string as well:

```
ssssssssss
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Oh back again. Make sure the last one has an `i` if you are truly passing in the `$_POST['emp_id']` value which is an integer from the other question